# iPhone alarm doesn't go off sometimes!

Tags: iphone, alarm

At times, the alarm in my iPhone 4S sometimes doesn't go off as set. Or actually, it goes off and I see the corresponding UI on the screen but there is NO sound.

This happens very randomly, may be once in ten times but is obviously not acceptable in an alarm application.

This mostly happens when the phone is in silent mode (which is still NOT expected behavior I am sure) but has also happened a couple times when the phone was non-silent.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? Had this type of problem with my iPhone 5 and now my iPhone 6.

Comment: Also make sure your phone isn't on charge as mine never goes off when it's on charge

Answer (score 2):

This could have to do with a software issue on the phone. Try backing up your phone via iCloud or computer, then wipe and restore it as new. If it doesn’t fix the problem, take your device to Apple as it could be an internal hardware issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting 3 alarms all roughly the same time eg: you want to get up at 08:00am set one for 07:59am one for 08:00am and one for 08:01am and it should work. That's what I do anyway because this happens constantly on my iPhone 6 plus and also my iPhone 4. Obviously your boss doesn't believe you when you use this excuse :)